# Override base url for c:url

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm going to have my Spring MVC web application deployed at Tomcat hidden behind Apache Web Server. I have both Tomcat and Apache deployed on same physical machine, but Tomcat is on port 81, while Apache is on port 80.

Apache is configured to redirect requests to Tomcat. In my web application I use `c:url` tag (JSTL/core) to format URLs properly. This works fine when I access Tomcat directly, but when I access Tomcat via Apache, URLs are just wrong.

So, when accessing Tomcat directly, web application is available at    `http://localhost:81/MyWebApplication/`, and when accessing via Apache, it's `http://sub.domain/`.

As far as I understand, the issue is that requests that Apache sends to Tomcat are in fact the real ones like `http://localhost:81/MyWebApplication/something`, so when JSPs are rendered, `c:url` is built based on these real requests and sure the app thinks it's deployed at `localhost:81`.

I'd prefer not to make any changes to Apache configuration, just because there's a bunch of other applications (not only Java) on same machine configured same way and they work fine.

**The question is:**

**What is the most adequate way to have explicitly defined base URL available to all JSPs? Ideally, it would be great just to somehow change `c:url`'s base URL to the correct one I want to use.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the Tomcat configuration, modify the appropriate connector

```
<Connector ... proxyName="apache-domain" proxyPort="80" />
```

in Tomcat's server.xml to pass the real domain and port to the app.

Comment: And what if I have 2 different application in this Tomcat, each accessible via its own virtual host?